# Caratheodory's method

Tags: measure-theory

The theorem is: Let X be a set and $\theta$ an outer measure on X.

Set $\sum= \{E: E \subseteq X, \theta A=\theta(A  \cap E)+ \theta(A \backslash\ E)$ for every $A \subseteq X\}$

What is the intuition behind this definition? and what does the Caratheodory method try to achieve?

Why does the fact that $\theta$ is an outer measure important?

Comment: Another way of defining it: $\Sigma$ contains those subsets $E$ of $X$ such that whenever $E_1,E_2$ are disjoint and their union is $E$, $m^*(E)=m^*(E_1)+m^*(E_2)$. In other words, these are sets that, no matter how you break them into two disjoint pieces, the two pieces still add up to the same measure as the original set. If this is true, then in particular you will have $m(E)=m(E_1)+m(E_2)$ when $E_1,E_2$ are *measurable* subsets of $E$, which is essential to ending up with a measure at the end of the procedure.

Comment: what is the difference between m* and m?

Comment: $m^*$ is the outer measure, $m$ is the measure. The difference between them is just their domains ($m$ has a smaller domain in general).

Comment: In the theorem, why does the fact that $\theta$ is an outer measure imnportant?

Comment: Ultimately, the relevant theorem is: a finitely additive, countably monotone set function defined on a $\sigma$-algebra is countably additive. Finite additivity and the domain being a $\sigma$-algebra follow from the definition of $\Sigma$. Countable monotonicity follows from the original $\theta$ being an outer measure. I don't know how to give a short, intuitive explanation of this theorem, though.

Comment: As far as I know, Caratheodory's construction in notorious example of non-intuitive approach that gives results. The problem lies not in outer measure that restricts to measure on smaller domain, but in the very definition of measurable sets with respect to outer measure - I'm clueless why should this be "correct" definition other than that it works.

Comment: Duplicate of 667393 ... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667393/motivation-behind-the-definition-of-measurability/