# I was pondering how caratheodory came to the definition of measure

Tags: measure-theory

How are caratheodory definition of measure and measure of a set A defined by covering of a sequence of open intervals related to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/667529/3148) ... I cannot mark this as a duplicate, because that OP never accepted any answer.  Copy of my answer:

(Assuming $m^*$ is outer measure.) There is some information on this in a note included in Carathéodory's collected works.  It was previously known for Lebesgue measure in the real line, that a set $A$ is measurable if and only if
$$
m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E \cap A^c) = m^*(E)
$$
for all intervals $E$.  When Carathéodory wanted to do an abstract version of the theory (not necessarily Lebesgue measure), it is either nonsense (or of no use) to use intervals here.  Then he discovered that this same criterion, required for all sets, not just intervals, also holds for Lebesgue measure; so *that* could be used in the abstract setting.